# RDP connection won't use the saved credentials for certain remote computers

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm running Windows 10 and I'm trying to access a different Windows 10 machine via RDP. I saved the RDP file to include saving the credentials. Unfortunately for some machines this does not work. The username gets saved correctly but when I start the connection the first time without entering the credentials the login fails.

A login prompt is shown instead with the correct domain/username, with the error message that the login attempt failed. If I put in the password now the RDP connection is established correctly. Deleting the saved user credentials and trying to save them again results in the same problem. Even if I activate the check box "saved credentials", the next time I try to, it's back to the same problem.

I didn't discover any solution yet that would resolve the issue, any ideas?

Comment: Are you by chance using the same username for both machines?

Comment: yes, it's a domain account (but note, it works fine on other machines with the same version/build)

Comment: You are specifying the domain and the user when you attempt to login into the machine?  What exactly is different about those machines that don't seem to work?

Comment: with the login? nothing, just different IPs (same subnet)

Comment: No; I know the logins are identical since you indicated you are connected to an AD domain.  I am asking what is similar to those machines that are not working compared to the machines that are working.  Wondering what the delta is between the machines that are not working and the machines that are working.

Comment: At least two of them have the same basic installation ISO and Windows updates, from there all kinds of different settings and installed software, impossible to list it all without further some hints how I should narrow the list.

Comment: @Ramhound in case you are interested, the solution required changes on my machine. However I still wonder what the actual cause is. I think it's the NTLM settings on the remote machine. Do you have any information there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing a GPO did the trick: on the client you are using to connect to the remote machine (not on the remote machine!):

- open `gpedit.msc`
- goto `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation`.
- change the policy named “Allow delegating saved credentials with
  NTLM-only server authentication” to `active`
- add all remote computers to the list by adding `TERMSRV/*` (you can specify single machines and domains as well, see link)
- force a policy update by executing `gpupdate /force`

[here's a good article](https://theitbros.com/enable-saved-credentials-usage-rdp/) about it with a few additional options.

Note: activating the policy named `Allow delegating saved credentials` wasn't necessary in my case