# Why my Remote Desktop Stored credentials do not work on a connection to a Windows Server 2022?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows Server 2022 which I access via RDP. I have stored my credentials of the Windows Server user, but every time that I try to log-in via RDP, it prompts me to enter the password of the server's user, saying the following: the logon attempt failed (referring to saved credentials).

I have stored my credentials on my Windows 11 PC, but it do not "read" them, I think is a problem about some Windows Server policy or something similar, because when I do it the same to my other Windows 10 PC (not server) it stores the credentials and they work normally.

Any help is really appreciate it.

Comment: How have you stored the credential and how are you invoking RDP?

Comment: With the RDP Windows 11 client itself, I stored them opt-in on the remember my credentials

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1693095/rdp-connection-wont-use-the-saved-credentials-for-certain-remote-computers) help?

Comment: I already tried, but no, it doesn't work.

Comment: If someone else comes across this - This link worked for me https://superuser.com/questions/1756354/windows-defender-credential-guard-does-not-allow-using-saved-credentials-for-r

Comment: I have reinstalled Windows 'cause I had more problems, apart this one. Thanks anyway for all the help